# Are all human beings capable of self-control?

Tags: sin, creation, human

I have been trying to find an answer to this according to the Hindu holy texts, but I cannot find reference to this in the Gita.

Are all human beings capable of self-control or are there human beings that cannot control themselves even if they try to exert discipline? For example, what about in the case of a person who sexually assaults people, claiming that they cannot help it and that they have no control over their actions.

Another example being Tourrette's syndrome. People with this disorder uncontrollably exclaim swear words and seem to not be able to do anything to stop themselves.

Is it possible for a person to have absolutely no control over their urges or is this false?

What do the scriptures say about the nature of discipline and control? If it is possible that some people have no control, how do we distinguish those who do bad things because they can't help it from those who can?

Comment: Hello there. Thank you for your contribution. I understand that even if some people do not do good they will be punished by someone who knows good from evil, but can you directly address the question in regards to whether the people commiting evil have any control over this?

Comment: @UdayKrishna so does that mean that as all beings have some Sattva guna they have some self control but not as much as others? Or do some humans not have any Sattva guna?

Comment: It is nothing to do with the religion, explain to others about your problem, they should understand it. One can control sexual feelings through meditation. Tourrette is self-diagnosable. Eat healthy food. Keep your stomach full always.

Comment: This is explained by Krishna in the Gita. See Gita Chapter 16 on those who have no control over their urges. See Gita Chapter 17 on how to distinguish between those with sattva and those with tamasic tendencies. Tourette's syndrome has nothing to do with sattva and tamas and is not an appropriate example. Tourette's is an organic disease. What is swearing to one person is not swearing to another. You are mixing up two different ideas.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda  in Chapter 16, at least in the translation I have, Vishnu describes those with no control as born of the demonic condition. Does this mean that they cannot be improved and are pre-destined to be bad people?

Comment: depends on what you mean by ALL humans. can a human being in a coma have self-control? how about a mentally retarded person? or a baby or a really old man who cannot even control their bowel movements? Obviously not ALL humans can have self control. But their own mind is the witness as to whether they really cannot control, or whether they're lying (to themselves or to others). at end of day, God is watching their conscience, and punishment will fit the crime exactly.

Comment: @ram Ram has said it correctly.